# How to transition between any two ViewControllers in Cocoa Touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm fairly new iOS development. I have multiple `viewController`s for my app, for example -

- A login screen
- A main / my profile screen
- A leader board / standings screen
- etc..

Each of these screens has its own `viewController`.

What's the best way to transition between any two arbitrary `viewController`s with an animation?

My current approach is -

1. Keep a reference to each `viewController` in `AppDelegate.m`
2. Keep changing the window's root controller as needed

This is both cumbersome and seems pretty inefficient, plus I'm not quite sure how to incorprate animated transitions here.

I see some examples with `UINavigationController`, but it seems like that operates as a "stack" of views that you can go into and then back out of. I'm not looking to keep a history here, just switch from any view to another.

Any good ways to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at UITabBarController, except for the login it may be useful

Comment: Yes, but then the tab bar is displayed at the bottom, correct?

Answer (score 2):

Try this Code.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (strong,nonatomic) LoginViewController *loginVC;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

   self.loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
   self.loginVC.title = @"Login Page";

   self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.loginVC];

   self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

LoginViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyProfileViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic)MyProfileViewController *myProfileVC;

@end
```

Login button action in LoginViewController.m file

```
- (IBAction)pushMyProfileView:(id)sender
{
    self.myProfileVC = [[MyProfileViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myProfileVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: So this is useful for transitioning between two specific views, but if I had 8 view controllers for example, each viewController would need to store references to the other 7.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can achieve that by using:

1. Apple containers (UINavigationController, UITabbarController, UISplitController)
2. Containment API
3. Using "normal" view controller and modal presentation

Containment API is probably what you are looking for, you create a UIViewController that is responsible to manage the presentation of its child view controllers. Here is [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html), there are plenty of examples inside.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner I believe the easiest solution for you it to use a `Storyboard` and create a segue between your View Controller.

Inside your ViewController you should override `prepareForSegue:` method to pass data to the `segue.destinationViewController`